# Fonts don't load in the pdf viewer

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have currently a problem with PdfSharp/MigraDoc and a pdf viewer. I have used the [EZFontResolver made by Thomas](http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/2015/12/11/ezfontresolver-a-generic-font-resolver-for-pdfsharp-and-migradoc/) to be able to generate pdfs with custom fonts. Unfortunately the pdf viewer is unable to render the font, and I have no idea why. I have seen a bug [described by Travis](http://developer.th-soft.com/developer/2015/12/11/ezfontresolver-a-generic-font-resolver-for-pdfsharp-and-migradoc/#comment-17) on Thomas' blog, which noted, that if EZFontResolver doesn't have multiple bold/italic symbol recognition (for example "fontname|b|b"), than **PdfDocumentRenderer.RenderDocument()** fails. The point is, when I try something like this:

```
Document document = DdlReader.DocumentFromString(ddl);
_renderer = new DocumentRenderer(document);
_renderer.PrepareDocument();
```

than the EZFontResolver is being asked for fonts with names like "customfont|b|b" (it doesn't happen when I use only **PdfDocument.Save(...)**) instead of "customfont".

My pdf viewer overrides DocumentViewer and views FixedDocument class instances. The funny thing is that the saved pdf file has all the fonts set, but the preview is unable to do that (and that is my big problem). All of this happens even though I return the right font with the resolver.

**EDIT:**

The ddl is a string which looks something like this:

```
"\\document
[
  Info
  {
    Title = \"My file\"
    Subject = \"My pdf file\"
    Author = \"mikes\"
  }
]
{
  \\styles
  {
    Heading1 : Normal
    {
      Font
      {
        Name = \"My custom font\"
        Bold = true
      }
      ParagraphFormat
      {
        Alignment = Center
        SpaceBefore = \"0.5cm\"
        SpaceAfter = \"0.5cm\"
      }
    }

    header : Normal
    {
      Font
      {
        Name = \"My custom font\"
        Size = 6
      }
      ParagraphFormat
      {
        Alignment = Center
      }
    }
```

And when I deleted the bug fix by Travis, the exception was thrown in the **_renderer.PrepareDocument()** (after fix, the stack trace showed that the source of multiple "|b" was also out of there).

Answer (score 1):

Simulated bold and simulated italics use the regular font, but a transformation is applied.

Therefore the simulation will not work if the PDF viewer does not support those transformations.

The DocumentViewer that comes with MigraDoc does not display PDF files, it displays MigraDoc documents. For technical reasons it cannot use fonts supplied via the IFontResolver interface. EZFontResolver is an implementation of IFontResolver.

With respect to "customfont|b|b": I cannot say whether this is a bug or the regular behaviour. Please provide an MCVE (complete sample) if you think it is a bug.

Comment: So is it possible to set a custom font in the MigraDoc file in any other way? With the bug, it's really hard for me to show the whole process, but I'll try.

Comment: The MDDDL file describes a document and any font can be "used" here. The renderer that creates PDF files supports the interface used by EZFontResolver and you can use it to add custom fonts. The renderer used by DocumentViewer does not support EZFontResolver - you can use installed fonts or XPrivateFontCollection for the GDI build. The fonts supplied with EZFontResolver will be embedded in the PDF file and can be used by any PDF viewer.